# How to connect dtd file

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I have made a small XML file and DTD file and I would like to test if the validation from the dtd file is work working as I see no changes. Is there anything that needs to be changed here it or is this okay as it is? if there are any changes which need to be made what are they?

---xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE furiture_shop SYSTEM "FS_18023702.dtd">
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="FS_18023702.css"?>-->

<furiture_shop>
    <logo>

    </logo>
    <furiture>
        <name>SLATTUM</name>
        <furiture_type>Bed: Folding beds</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 569764</item_number>
        <description>Description: Upholstered bed frame, Knisa light grey, Standard Double</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 8</quantity>
        <price>Price: £85.00</price>
        <deliery>Express Delivery</deliery>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>

        <name>VANGSTA</name>
        <furiture_type>Bed: Chair bed</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 789123</item_number>
        <description>Description: Upholstered in dark grey Fernando fabric, this multi-functional piece contains a space saving guest bed which can easily and quickly fold back into a footstool when not in use. Comfort is provided thanks to its foam filled cushioning.  </description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 65</quantity>
        <price>Price: £90.00</price>
        <deliery>Free Delivery</deliery>
        <manufacturer>
            <sub>Manufacturer: </sub>
        unite manufacturer
        </manufacturer>

        <colour>
            <sub>Colour: </sub>
            Black
        </colour>

        <materials>
            <sub>Material: </sub>
            Pine wood
        </materials>

        <optional>
            <arms>Scroll Arms</arms>
        </optional>         

    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>LOBERGET</name>
        <furiture_type>Sofa: 3 Seater Sofa</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 324587</item_number>
        <description>Description: An skilfully handcrafted, deep buttoned sofa with elegant curvaceous lines</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 16</quantity>
        <price>Price: £800.00</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>SIBBEN</name>
        <furiture_type>Sofa: 6 Seater Modular Sofas</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 598234</item_number>
        <description>Description: This soft and cosy sofa will have a long life as the seat cushions are filled with high resilience foam that gives good support for your body and quickly regains its original shape when you get up.</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 20</quantity>
        <price>Price: £160</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>MALM</name>
        <furiture_type>Sofa</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 157894</item_number>
        <description>Description: MALM is a generous seating series with a soft, deep seat and comfortable support for your back.</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 1</quantity>
        <price>Price: £350.00 </price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>HEMNES</name>
        <furiture_type>Dining Table</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 597234</item_number>
        <description>Description: Extendable dining table with 1 extra leaf seats 4-6; makes it possible to adjust the table size according to need.</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 8</quantity>
        <price>Price: £635.00</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>NIKKEBY</name>
        <furiture_type>Bed: Chair bed</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 649782</item_number>
        <description>Description: A simple, firm foam mattress for use every night. Use your space at home more efficiently with an chair that doubles as a bed at night.</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 12</quantity>
        <price>Price: £140</price>
        <deliery>Free Delivery</deliery>
        <manufacturer>
            <sub>Manufacturer: </sub>
            Michael phillps inc
        </manufacturer>

        <colour>
            <sub>Colour: </sub>
            Red
        </colour>

        <materials>
            <sub>Material: </sub>
            Steel frame, foam mattress 
        </materials>

        <optional>
            <arms>Scroll Arms</arms>    
        </optional>         
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>PLATSA</name>
        <furiture_type>Dining table</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 546793</item_number>
        <description>Description:Large extendable dining room table suitable for 8 - 12 people </description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 13</quantity>
        <price>Price: £1260.00</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>HYLLIS</name>
        <furiture_type>Armchair</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 228944</item_number>
        <description>Description: The hardwood frame and fibre wrapped foam filled padded seat cushion allow for a supportive sit</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 8</quantity>
        <price>Price: £190.00</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>KOLBJORN</name>
        <furiture_type>Dining table</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 334489</item_number>
        <description>Description: A stylish and contemporary dining table. Able to seat up to 6 diners, this grey high-gloss dining set is perfect for kitchens or smaller dining rooms.</description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 16</quantity>
        <price>Price: £69.99</price>
    </furiture>

    <furiture>
        <name>TORDH</name>
        <furiture_type>Armchair</furiture_type>
        <item_number>Item ID: 645873</item_number>
        <description>Description: With its compact design and unique silhouette, Herman is ideal for small spaces. The T-shaped seat cushion and bolster cushions make it both comfy and stylish. </description>
        <quantity>Amount Available: 13</quantity>
        <price>Price: £125.99</price>
    </furiture>

    <shop_Details>
        <store_name>The Furiture shop</store_name>
        <address>
            <street>51 Green Street</street>
            <town>Camden</town>
            <city>London</city>
            <postcode>N1 C56L</postcode>
        </address>
        <contact_num>
            <phone>Telephone: 0108 359 1762</phone>
            <fax>Fax: 0108 359 1763</fax>
        </contact_num>
        <siteadd>www.tfs.co.uk</siteadd>
    </shop_Details>
</furiture_shop>
```

---ddt file---
this is the dtd file

```
<!ELEMENT furiture_shop (logo,furiture,shop_Details)>
<!ELEMENT logo EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT furiture (name,furiture_type,item_number,description,quantity,price,deliery*,manufacturer*,colour*,materials*,optional?)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT furiture_type (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT item_number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT deliery (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT manufacturer (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT colour(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT materials(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT optional (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT shop_Details (store_name,address,contact_num,siteadd)>
<!ELEMENT address (street,town,city,postcode)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT town (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT postcode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contact_num (phone,fax)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fax (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT siteadd (PCDATA)>
```

Comment: Just make sure you are running it using a validating parser. If you don't know how to do that, tell us what parser you are using and how you are invoking it.

Comment: The DTD looks "connected" with the doctype declaration ok. Now you just need a validating parser (like Michael Kay suggested). There will definitely be validation errors.

Comment: thanks for the help